# React component doesn't render in a razor page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a react component and i want to render it in a razor page. But i don't want to be rendered in a div. Cause i know it's works with ReactDOM.render. But it's not what i want.
I must use it as a tag in a razor page, so if i have the class App i will use it as .
But, when i try to load it doesn't show anything but inspector's console of the page doesn'y throw any error. So, do i miss something to import or a function to be needed? The project is a ASP.NET CORE MCV and my purpose is to integrate React in a Razor page,and the request is exactly use the class as tag. I tried to use pure JS file but with the same result.

App.jsx

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { message: 'Hello, World! aa' };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.state.message}</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json;
@using SportData.Web.Models;
@using System.Web.Optimization;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices


@model SportContainer





<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/remarkable/1.7.1/remarkable.min.js"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/js/App.jsx")" type="module"></script>

<App></App>
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - SportData</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <script>var exports = {};</script>

    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/card.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</head>
<body>
     
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>
   

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>

</html>
```

package.json

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.20.7",
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.12",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel SportData.Web/wwwroot/js --out-dir SportData.Web/wwwroot/js/build --presets @babel/preset-react"
  },
  "type":"module"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You might find it useful to read up on https://reactjs.net/

You might not necessarily need to use that package, but maybe there's something you can learn from how it works, given it's open source https://github.com/reactjs/React.NET

Comment: I will read it, but before the lecture...Could you give some details that i have to pay attention. (in case, looking at the code I posted, you already have the solution)

Comment: I don't have to use server rendering with '@Html.React'. I have to user exactly the component as a tag <App>. Cause i know '@Html.Rect' works.

Comment: Yeh I don't know a ton about that project, I just used it one time as a POC for using ASP.NET MVC with React.. The thing that springs to mind though, is you are including the component on the page, and react on the page, but there's nothing to bootstrap it all.

e.g. like they have here:
https://github.com/reactjs/React.NET/blob/6d4a15acbc4004c5c9be833dd07328e63c791578/src/React.Template/reactnet-vanilla/Views/Home/Index.cshtml

Although you could be right, maybe that's only for SSR

Comment: So, you don't know or ever used the component as a tag?

Comment: Ah right yeh sorry, I missed that little nuance in the question. I don't even know if that's possible, you're basically using a JSX tag directly in the HTML.

Comment: reactjs.net isn't a solution. This isn't what he needs. Embedding react in a cshtml file is very very possible. Its just javascript that you can embed in a view. Ultimately, cshtml files are just html files.